# How to add permissions for custom settings/metadata for managed package

Tags: managed-package, customsetting, permission-sets, custom-metadata

I have a managed package that are using custom metadata and custom settings and I want to use permission sets so we can control the access permission of these custom metadata and custom settings. I tried setting them in permission sets but I couldn't get the metadata from my scratch orgs.

Are they even allowed to be packaged for managed packaged?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I can't get the updated permission set metadata of my scratch org but when I updated the permission set of my packaging org directly, I was able to package the permission set with the custom settings/metadata.